# Edge case in the change of base formula for logs

Tags: proof-explanation, logarithms

I know that for any $a,b > 0$, we have
$$
\log_a x = \frac{\log_c x}{\log_c a}.
$$
The proof I'm accustomed to is something like this:

> Let $y = \log_a x$. Then $a^y = x$ by definition. Apply the function $\log_c (x)$ to both sides, giving $\log_c (a^y) = \log_c x$. By the properties of logs, this gives
> $$ 
> y \log_c a = \log_c x.
> $$
> Dividing by $\log_c a$ then gives the result.

My question is on the edge case where $\log_c a = 0$ and the division is impossible. For example, if $c = e$ and $a = 1$. Is there a way to treat that case separately? Do I need to require, for example, that $a > 1$?

Comment: The number $1$ cannot be the base of a logarithm.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I thought I was making $e$ the base of the logarithm. But why can't I use 1? I thought I couldn't use just 0 and negative numbers.

Comment: @Cardinality You first already let $y=\log_1 x$, with base $1$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What @Cardinality said.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Ok, so that case I mentioned isn't even possible with this change of base formula. Is there any other possibility of dividing by $0$? Otherwise, I think I'm ok with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you have $1^y = x$ by definition, either $x=1$ and all real $y$ satisfy the equation, or $x\ne 1$ and no real $y$ satisfy the equation. So $\log_1 x$ is not a function that gives a unique value for each $x$.

Comment: The only dividing by $0$ possible in that formula is if $\log_c a = 1$.  But that occurs if and only if $a =1$.  But if $a =1$ we can not have $a$ as a base of a log.  The proper stating of the change of log base should be:  If $a, c$ are any legitimate bases for logs (that is to say both positive and not equal to $1$) then $\log_c x = \frac {\log_a x}{\log_c a}$ for all $x > 0$.... There is no invalided cases. ($a\ne 1$ so $\log_c a\ne 0$ and for all $x>0$, $\log_a x,\log_c x$ are defined but never divided by so they can be equal to $0$.)

Answer (score 1):

As @John Wayland Bales said in comments, $1$ cannot be the base of logarithms. Here is why:

If $a>0$, the function $f_a(x)=a^x$ is defined for all real numbers.

1. When $a\neq 1$, it is a monotonic function (increasing when $a>0$ and decreasing when $0<a<1$) so we can define its inverse function $f_a^{-1}\log_a$. This is what allows the property

$$y=a^x \iff x=\log_a(y)$$

for every $x\in\mathbb R$, $y>0$ (since the range of $f_a$ is $(0,\infty)$ when $a\neq 1$)

2. On the other hand, when $a=1$, the function $f_1$ is constant, equal to $1$, so has no inverse function.

---

Note also that the Change of Base formula comes with conditions with the real numbers involved (as with every formula!):

> If $a$ and $c$ are positive integers **such that $a\neq 1$ and $c\neq 1$** and $x>0$, then
> $$\log_a(x) = \frac{\log_c(x)}{\log_c(a)}$$

If you are worried about division by $0$, you can just rewrite the formula as $\log_c(x)=\log_a(x)\log_c(a)$ and the problem is gone! Actually, as others pointed out in comments, $\log_c(a)$ is never equal to $0$ since

$$\log_c(a)=0 \iff a=1$$

whatever the value of $c$.